# Controlling motors in ROS Kinetic on Raspberry Pi 3B

Tags: raspberrypi, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm new to ROS and I followed this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLiI_IRedhI

I did not use the exact same car but a simple car with a servo motor and a DC motor instead.

At 9:00 of the video, he started to publish some topics but I don't know what servo 1 and servo 2 mean, I have no idea where I should connect the motors to the Raspberry Pi.

Please don't mind my dumb question and thanks for any help.

Some spec:

Raspberry Pi 3B

Ubuntu Mate 16.04

ROS Kinetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327704/controlling-motors-in-ros-kinetic-on-raspberry-pi-3b/) by [IvanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/43923/ivans/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-07-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-07-04**:
Perhaps you should leave a comment on the video? The author seems to be responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will find all answers at https://www.donkeycar.com/

Short answer:

Steering: RPI3--->I2C--->Controller---Servo

Throttle: RPI3--->I2C--->Controller--->ESC--->DC-Motor

Enjoy the FAQ

Cheers

Chrimo

---

Originally posted by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) with karma: 476 on 2019-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1